How to fetch content from websites?
I have a fetch_website_content(url) function that is supposed to fetch content from a website, but it is not fetching the content. I want to extract the main text from the website (without the ads and other news) Let's say this is the website from which I want to get the content: bbc.com/sport/football/articles/c6p2geyl0l4o
When I print the content in the terminal, I get an empty screen. What could be the reason?
def fetch_website_content(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10) 
        response.raise_for_status()
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Extract all text content from the page
        text_content = soup.get_text(separator='\n\n').strip()
        
        return text_content
    
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching {url}: {str(e)}")
        return None


Please include a minimal reproducible example.  What is the content you're trying to get?  What kind of content are you expecting?

I want to extract the main text from the website. Let's say this is the website from which I want to get the content: https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/articles/c6p2geyl0l4o

It is fetching the content, all of the content. If you want exclusively the main text, you need to go into that full html you are pulling, and parse the parts that contain that main content which is in the <main id=main-content> tag.
Then from there can pull out the headline, date published, and text block. Format however you like, but I kept it in the way you have above with the newlines and spaces for each <p> paragraph in the article text.
Code:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def fetch_website_content(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10) 
        response.raise_for_status()
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Extract all text content from the page
        main_content = soup.find('main', {'id':'main-content'})
        
        headline = main_content.find(attrs={'id':'main-heading'}).text.strip()
        datePublished = main_content.find('time').text.strip()
        timeStamp = main_content.find('time')['datetime'] # If you want the exact timestamp
        
        text_block = main_content.find(attrs={'data-component':'text-block'})
        
        paragraphs = text_block.find_all('p')
        formatted_text = '\n\n'.join(p.get_text() for p in paragraphs)

        
        text_content = '\n\n'.join([headline, datePublished, formatted_text])

        return text_content
    
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching {url}: {str(e)}")
        return None
    
    
url = 'https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/articles/c6p2geyl0l4o'
text_content = fetch_website_content(url)


print(text_content)

Output:
Bayern sign Fulham midfielder Palhinha until 2028

11 July 2024

Bayern Munich have signed midfielder Joao Palhinha from Fulham on a four-year-year contract until June 2028 for Â£42.3m, plus Â£4.2m in add-ons. 

The 28-year-old Portugal international joins the Bundesliga club a year after their initial deal to sign him collapsed. 

âThis is one of the happiest days of my life," Palhinha told the club's website. , external

"I'm now playing for one of the top clubs in Europe. It's a dream come true for me, and I'm very proud of that."

Palhinha joined Fulham from Sporting Lisbon in 2022 for around Â£17m.

He won the club's Player of the Year award during his opening season at Craven Cottage.

The midfielder made 79 appearances over two seasons in west London, scoring eight times.

Palhinha follows Crystal Palace winger Michael Olise to Bayern. 

English defender Eric Dier has also joined the Bundesliga club permanently after playing for them on loan from Tottenham last season.

Bayern's 11-year hold on the German title was ended by Bayer Leverkusen in 2023-24.


The example you gave runs just fine for me. I get the text contents of the html tags
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def fetch_website_content(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10) 
        response.raise_for_status()
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Extract all text content from the page
        text_content = soup.get_text(separator='\n\n').strip()
        
        return text_content
    
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error fetching {url}: {str(e)}")
        return None
print(fetch_website_content("https://www.google.com"))

The reason you are seeing nothing could be that you are only returning text content and not the full HTML source.
